# Prevent div overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with div overlapping, I believe it's to do with different screen resolutions.

This is my CSS:

```
#menu {
 background: #fff;
 width: 790px;
}

#site {
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 background: #fff;
 width: 1075px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
 padding: 2px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}

#social {
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
 padding: 5px;
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}

#categories {
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #000;
 padding: 5px;
 float:left;
 position:fixed;
 top: 250px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0px #000;
}

#categories img {
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div align="center">
<div id="social">
<h3 style="font-size:18px">Follow Us!</h3>
<a href="#">
<img src="logo.png" />
</a>
<a href="#">
<img src="logo2.png">
</a>
</div>

<div id="categories">
<h3 style="font-size:18px">Categories!</h3>
<a href="categories.php">
<img src="gamereviewresized.png">
</a>
</div>
```

When I visit my site, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/6v5qaj
It looks like this for someone with a different screen resolution though: http://prntscr.com/6v5qp3

Help would be appreciated on how to prevent overlapping on different resolutions.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean the logo overlapping ? I.E the green container with the white box ?

Comment: I mean like in my first image, there's a blue gap between the two boxes. There isn't however in the second screenshot.

Comment: You could either use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and use different css for smaller viewports, or use javascript to test if they are overlapping and then resize the right element

Comment: @JugglingBob , i have added an answer , if that helps you in any way , consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#site` div has a `1075px` fixed width and `auto` left and right margins.

```
#site {
 width: 1075px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Meanwhile, the *Game Reviews* tab has a fixed-width of `100px`.

Consequently, any screen width less than `1275px` (where the margin between the left-edge of the screen and the left-edge of `#site` is narrower than `100px`) will lead to the *Game Reviews* tab overlapping `#site`.

Suggestions:

1) Give `#site` a left-hand margin wider than the `100px` wide *Game Reviews* tab (and right-hand margin to match)

2) For `#site`, change the `width: 1075px;` declaration to `max-width: 1075px;` (this will enable the width of `#site` to shrink when the screen is narrower than `1275px`).

**Example:**

```
#site {
 max-width: 1075px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-right: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use media queries to adjust the height the image , in your case i am guessing the image is :

```
<img src="gamereviewresized.png">
```

here is a simple example how you can adjust the height of a img using a media query :

```
<img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg" alt="">
```

CSS ::

```
img{
    max-width:400px;
    height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
           img{
            max-width:200px;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
```

fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eqE9J/165/) , reduce the width of the display section to below 480px to see what i mean .

you can study more media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).